# Message "Ours and foreign blockchain have only genesis block in common... o.O"

Tags: monerod, blockchain, genesisblock

When I'm syncing the blockchain for the fist time, I have this error message 8 times

> 2016-Sep-26 19:58:50.608535 [P2P3]ERROR /tmp/monero/src/monero-0.10.0/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1835 **Ours and foreign blockchain have only genesis block in common... o.O**
>
> 2016-Sep-26 19:58:51.845898 [P2P9][139.59.11.117:18080 OUT]Sync data returned unknown top block: 1 -> 1144519 [1144518 blocks (888 days) behind]
>
> SYNCHRONIZATION started

and then I only have the regular information message

> Synced 401/1144519

Should I care about this error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing to worry, when you are starting to sync and theres a node trying to sync with you, it sends the list of blocks it has for catching up but since you have nothing but the genesis block you see this message.

Comment: If it's not really an error shouldn't the language of the messages be adjusted?

Comment: That message has been fixed already in git master. Won't appear in v0.10.1.